# Can a Devil Fruit user survive under water?

Tags: one-piece

The Devil Fruit eaters lose their ability to swim, but it's not been said that they would also lose their ability to breathe under water.

Like if a Fish-Man eats a Devil Fruit, he would lose his ability to swim, but wouldn't he be able to breathe under water due to being a Fish-Man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fish-men retain their ability to breathe underwater, even if they have a devil fruit.
As an example, we have [Jack the Drought](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Jack) of the Beasts Pirates. He is a giant grouper fish-man and ate the Zou Zou no Mi, Model: Mammoth.

> Since he is a Devil Fruit user, he has lost the ability to swim, but because he is a fish-man, he can breathe underwater. Though, he still would not be able to move if he falls into the water.

We see him in [Chapter 824](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_824) of the manga underwater being conscious but unable to move.